# AngularJS 1.x Component testing with Karma resolve promise to test success function (spyOn)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm lost. I try to test if `state.go` is called after a `ApiServiceMock` has resolved a promise after a fake login.
For this test I get:
`Expected spy go to have been called.`

If I test another function which is directly triggering `state.go` it works. So I guess the promise isn't being resolved in the first place.

Using Angular Components and testing is quite new to me. Would be great if someone could give me a hint what I'm doing wrong or let me know if the whole approach is wrong in the first place.

**login.component.ctrl.js**

```
  module.exports = function LoginComponentCtrl($state, $log, apiService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.submit = function() {
      apiService
        .login(vm.username, vm.password)
          .then(function(response) {
            $state.go('storeDetail');
          })
          .catch(function(errData) {
            $log.error(errData);
          });
    };
  };
```

**login.spec.js**

```
var app = require('../../app.js');
var login = require('./login.module.js');

describe('login', function() {

  var controller;
  var element;
  var scope;
  var state;
  var ApiServiceMock;
  var StateMock;
  var deferred;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(app));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module(login));

  describe('Component: login', function () {

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $componentController, $q){
      deferred = $q.defer();

      ApiServiceMock = {
        login: function () {
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      };

      StateMock = {
        go:  function () {
          return true;
        }
      };

      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $componentController('login', {
        $scope: scope,
        apiService: ApiServiceMock,
        $state: StateMock
      });
      element = angular.element('<login></login>');
      element = $compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$apply();
    }));

    it('on successful login', function() {
      controller.username = 'Michael Jackson';
      controller.password = 'dangerous123';

      spyOn(StateMock, 'go').and.callThrough();

      controller.submit();

      deferred.resolve();
      scope.$digest();

      expect(StateMock.go).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }););
  });
});
```

Let me know if I can add further information to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just directly return resolved promise from your mock service.

Try this

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $componentController, $q){
  ApiServiceMock = {
    login: function () {
      return $q.resolve({}); // if angular version is 1.4+
    //return $q.when({}); // if angular less than 1.4
    }
  };

  StateMock = {
    go:  function () {
      return true;
    }
  };

  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  controller = $componentController('login', {
    $scope: scope,
    apiService: ApiServiceMock,
    $state: StateMock
  });
  element = angular.element('<login></login>');
  element = $compile(element)(scope);
  scope.$apply();
}));

it('on successful login', function() {
  controller.username = 'Michael Jackson';
  controller.password = 'dangerous123';

  spyOn(StateMock, 'go').and.callThrough();

  controller.submit();

  scope.$digest();

  expect(StateMock.go).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
);
```

Comment: Thx @Jay, that helped me to see that I missed `{}` within the `deferred.resolve()`. This also works within the `it`.  

So solution is: `deferred.resolve({});`